# Two Turtles Breeds _ one breed is the variable of the other?

Tags: netlogo

I've got a doozy of a Netlogo question.  If I have two different breeds of turtles, can the sum of a specified number of one breed's variables BE THE VARIABLE of the other breed?

Here is my train of thought.  I’d like to model water usage of multiple households, but that water usage of a household needs to be dependent on a) the fixed values of the house (like water used by a faucet) * b) frequency of use of faucet by a person.  With each household containing either 1 or more person (people) and that frequency of use can vary person to person.

The idea of using two turtle breeds would allow me to see how the decisions made by one breed affects the other.

Here is my pseudo code to help illustrate what I was thinking (not intended to be a working code)

```
globals []

breed [People person] 
breed [Community household]

People-own [frequency]
Community-own [waterusefacuet HouseholdWaterUse]

;; =================================================================================================================
;; =================================================================================================================

to setup
  clear-all
  HouseholdCreation
  PersonCreation
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask Community [WaterConsumption]
  tick
end

;; =================================================================================================================
;; =================================================================================================================

to HouseholdCreation
  ask patches [ sprout-Community n of 1 [
    set size 1.0 set shape "square" set color blue 
    set waterusefacuet (1)
  ] ]
end


to PersonCreation
  ask Community [ hatch-People 1 [
   set size 0.5 set shape "circle" set color red
   set frequency (1 + random 4)
  ]]
end


to WaterConsumption
 Set HouseholdWaterUse (waterusefacuet * (frequency * # of people) )
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can the sum of a specified number of one breed's variables BE THE VARIABLE of the other breed?

Absolutely.

*snipsnip for clarification* : In my code here, I do not let the water use of people who live in a household BE the water use variable of that household. And generally I would recommend against a solution that lets the state of one (or more) agents be the state of another variable - unless there is a very good reason for it. Having states depend on each other is dangerous because you always have to make sure that you sync the values between agents. More importantly, it's often unnecessary. In my solution here, each person belongs to a household, and when that households calculates its total water use, it asks all its inhabitants to send them their use on that day, and then returns the sum of all those numbers. I hope that makes sense. If not, please do ask.

*< /snipsnip>

You need to use the `of` keyword though. `of` allows you direct access to variables from the context/perspective of one or more individual agent. So, let's say we have households and people, and people (because we all have different water use habits) have some frequency of water tap uses. In fact, we could have people draw the amount of water they use every day from a a normal distribution that is unique to them. Let's do that:

```
breed [people person]
breed [households household]
people-own [
  mean-use-per-day ;; mean use per day
  sd-use-per-day ;; standard dev per day
  my-household ;; the household to which a person belongs
]

to setup
  create-households 10 [
    hatch-people random 4 + 1 [ ;; between 1 and 4 people in a household
    set mean-use-per-day random 5 + 5 ;; mean 5-9
    set sd-use-per-day random-float 3 ;; sd 0.00-2.99
    set my-household myself ;; we set the person's household to the household that hatched them
   ]
]

to-report household-water-use ;; household reporter
  report sum [random-normal mean-use-per-day sd-use-per-day] of people with [my-household = myself] ;; this creates a list of water uses based on the random use of each person in the household.
end
```

in order to run this code, you can simply call

```
show [household-water-use] of households
```

from the command center. This will give you a list of the water use of each household. Or if you want to just see the water use of one household on one random day, you can try

```
show [household-water-use] of one-of households
```

Comment: Hey that worked out great, thank you for the advice.

Comment: Actually, I do have a follow up question. Is it possible for the person within a household to know which household they are in? What I mean is `my-household` is an `people` variable, can that person communicate with that house?  `of household (my-household)`

Comment: It can, although the code you posted at the end would not really make sense. The `my-household` people-variable holds a reference to the household agent, so you could do something like `ask one-of people [ ask my-household [ set size 10 ] ]` .

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply make each patch a household, have each patch have one or more turtles (persons), and then calculate household factors as patch factors? To define communities one could place patches into zones (e.g., if pxcor >= 5 and pxcor <=8 and pycor >=3 and pycor <= 6 set zone 1) <== not meant to be code, just the idea.

You could set patch size to make each patch small and specify a large zone of patches.